# Why is `timespec_get()` not supported by MinGW gcc 8.2.0 `-std=c11`?

Tags: c, mingw, iso, c11

Referring to the [N1570 Committee Draft of the ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **Programming languages - C** which dates back to April 12, 2011, there should be a function `timespec_get()` (see 7.27.2.5).

But MinGW gcc version 8.2.0 returns `warning: implicit declaration of function 'timespec_get'`, and `error: 'TIME_UTC' undeclared`, when compiling the following code snippet with `gcc -std=c11 snippet.c`:

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
   struct timespec tstart;
   timespec_get(&tstart, TIME_UTC);
   return 0;
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: I don't find that function in linux either.

Comment: This depends on your C library and not your compiler. Some systems are notoriously bad in supporting recent ;-) versions of C.

Comment: Still having this exact issue myself 11 months later.

Comment: MinGW-w64 versions built for UCRT do have `timespec_get` and `TIME_UTC`.
You can get an UCRT build of recent MinGW-w64 from https://winlibs.com/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `-std=c11`, you should use the `-D_UCRT` option for the compiler and `-lucrt` for the linker.
There is working CMakeLists.txt and cmake invocation

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project(timespec_get)

set(EXE_NAME test)
set(MAIN_SOURCES 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test.c
)

add_executable(${EXE_NAME} ${MAIN_SOURCES})
if (${MINGW})
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-W -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -D_UCRT")
    target_link_libraries(${EXE_NAME} -lucrt)
else ()
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-W -Wall -Wextra -std=c11")
endif ()
```

cmake invocation:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/mingw/toolchain-mingw64.cmake
```

and result

```
$ make
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test.dir/src/test.c.obj
[100%] Linking C executable test.exe
[100%] Built target test
```

Comment: This depends on MinGW flavor. E.g. if you're using MSYS2, you should probably install their version of GCC that does this by default, instead of trying to convince a different version to target ucrt.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat While you are definitely correct about this (to use the [mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc?repo=ucrt64) package in the *MSYS2 UCRT64* console), it's nevertheless possible to build the [*`timespec` Example*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec#Example) via `gcc test.c -std=C11 -D_UCRT -lucrt` in the *MSYS2 MINGW64* console — also in the Windows command line with the gcc that comes with Strawberry Perl 5.38.2, by the way.